# JSON - PHP vs C/C++

Tags: php, c, ajax, performance

I had a site working nicely in PHP. Then an acquaintance who works at Google got in my ear about how AJAX is the thing. So now I've rejigged the site to be in just HTML & javascript on the client-side making AJAX JSON calls to PHP scripts calling MySQL on the server side. Good caching, no page reloads. It was a good idea.

My question now, however, is this: How much faster might the site run if the server side was in a compiled language (say, C or C++) rather than PHP? (My original prototype was in C - in the terminal!) The PHP scripts are all basic security processing and then database calls to return JSON. How can you benchmark relative speeds? Just using firebug POST data in the console? Or is there a better way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is that simple, php interpretation will be a tiny fraction of the execution time, most of which will be taken by the connection to the db server. You can always look at Facebook's HipHop - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/ though

For benchmarking, something like

```
// first line of your code
$start_time = microtime( $get_as_float = TRUE );


// last line of your code
$time_end = microtime( $get_as_float = TRUE );
$execution_time = $time_end - $start_time;

echo '<!-- executed in: ', $execution_time , ' seconds -->';
```

will go a long way

I wouldn't use the times in Firebug as those depend on your connection speed/quality etc